# Pass array of structs as compound literal to a function

Tags: c, arrays, struct, compound-literals

I have an array declaration where I have initialized all the elements of the array with some initial value.

I want to now create the members of the array "on the fly"/on-demand without having to statically allocate all the members.

`test_t test_array[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; //Array initialized
func((uint32)&((test_t []){1, 2, 3, 4, 5});//Pass address of array member (created on demand)`

Compiling with an arm compiler and it gives me an "incomplete type is not allowed" error.

Is the syntax for the compound literal wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: i am not quite sure whether the second one is created on demand. i think it's created statically but tagged as readonly. hope somebody can dig this part out from standard.

Comment: I guess all the elements are statically initialized. I am just re-assigning it new values depending on some condition that takes place, (that's why on-demand) as opposed to hard-coding the values for all 10 members.

Comment: the first one is on demand. it's allocated in scope.

Comment: em... maybe i was wrong `If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object
has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with
the enclosing block.` from 6.5.2.5.5

Comment: The only thing I notice is that you're missing a single `)` on your call to `func` but I'm assuming that was a typo. I ran exactly this program, using `typedef int test_t` and replacing `uint32` with `int` as well and it compiled no problem on `clang 6.0` for OSX 10.11.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Thanks for the reply. So is this way legit to assign values to a member of an array of struct? I'm going wrong with my syntax somewhere..

Comment: maybe you can show your struct definition. it's related to how compound literals are initialized.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: Sorry I couldnt post as a comment. My editing was messed up :(

Comment: http://ideone.com/x0nPYW check your compiler options. there is no problem in the code itself, unless your compiler is not c99 compliant.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: I guess the other difference is that I initialized the array and then used compound literal on an initialized array of size 10. Maybe it worked in what you tried, since compound literal was used as an initializer itself ?

Comment: Tried initializing first and then using the compound literal. http://ideone.com/63MDFd  Turns out it works.. Possibly missing something in my compiler options then..

Answer (score 0):

@HuStmpHrrr: Sorry I couldn't post a comment, my editing wasn't coming out right.

The struct members are all bit-fields, I had provided only a sample example in my first post.

```
typedef struct 
{
uint32 a            : 32;
uint32 b            : 32;
uint32 c            : 16;
uint32 d            : 15;
uint32 e            : 1;
} test_t;
```